# Table is messed up on IE8 when updated and built using #each

Tags: ember.js

I want to build a table in which each row references an Ember object, and uses it to populate each column.

I built a dead simple jsfiddle in order exemplify:

http://jsfiddle.net/marklazz/yth8C/

This work in Chrome, FF & IE9.

But as you can notice, in IE8 the table is rendered down below where it started....is like it is being pushed down to the bottom...

By inspecting the final HTML, it seems to me that it has to do with the "shy" elements inserted by ember, could that be ?

Comment: can you copy/paste the HTML that gets generated in IE8?  This sounds like it may be an HTML shim issue: http://paulirish.com/2011/the-history-of-the-html5-shiv/

Comment: Can you file a bug in the Ember GitHub project?